# Different lineinfile to different domains in one task

Tags: ansible

I was trying to create a playbook to insert lines to /etc/hosts.
Tricky part was - exact line was different for host domain.
I've ended with following (working) playbook with 2 tasks:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Add line to /etc/hosts -UK"
      lineinfile: path=/etc/hosts
                  line='192.168.1.2 hostname.uk.com'
      when: ansible_domain == ".uk.com"
    - name: "Add line to /etc/hosts -US"
      lineinfile: path=/etc/hosts
                  line='192.168.255.255 hostname.us'
      when: ansible_domain == "us"
```

But I just don't like it :)
And what am I going to do, when I'll have 10 domains?
Is there a way to create a playbook with only one task to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
- hosts: all

  vars:
    my_mapping:
      .uk.com:
        ip: 192.168.1.2
        fqdn: hostname.uk.com
      us:
        ip: 192.168.255.255
        fqdn: hostname.us

  tasks:
    - name: Add line to /etc/hosts
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        line: "{{ my_mapping[ansible_domain].ip }} {{ my_mapping[ansible_domain].fqdn }}"
```

- create dictionary for mapping the values with the domain as the key
- refer to the dictionary values in the argument of the module